Make: how to pass pattern matched variable to a list
Let's say I have some variables in a makefile:
SUB_TEST1=PRJ1
SUB_TEST2=PRJ2
SUB_TEST3=PRJ3
…

I want to grab this list of variables and put it in a list, and then pass that to a target
SUB_TEST1=PRJ1
SUB_TEST2=PRJ2
SUB_TEST3=PRJ3

MYLIST:= $(wildcard SUB_*)
# or
# MYLIST:= $(foreach i,$(SUB_%),$(i))

test:
    echo "my variables list: $(MYLIST)"
…

Expected output:
my variables list: PRJ1 PRJ2 PRJ3 …

How can I do that thing?

This smacks of an XY Problem; what exactly do you hope to do with that list of variables? Often, keeping your stuff in a simple text file or external recipe you can include from your main Makefile might make more sense.

this is a simplificated example, at the end what i want to do is:
include prj.env (where my variables store, and lately users can add sub1...subN)
Create list of this variables and pass it to a target into a tcl script as an argument variable

With GNU make you can try:
MYLIST:= $(foreach v,$(filter SUB_%,$(.VARIABLES)),$(value $v))

The .VARIABLE special variable expands to a list of the names of all global variables defined so far. filter keeps only the variable names beginning with SUB_. foreach iterates over the found variable names. value expands the variable.
If your make is not GNU make and you cannot install it, but your make supports one form or another of the GNU make shell function, or the != variable assignment, you could process your own Makefile with, e.g., sed:
MYLIST != sed -n 's/^SUB_.*=\(.*\)/\1/p' Makefile

But this is more a dirty hack than a viable robust solution.

No, there is no mechanism for applying wildcards to variable names.
If, as in your example, your variables are systematically named like this, you could do something like
MYLIST := $(patsubst %,SUB_TEST%,$(shell bash -c 'echo  {1..3}'))

but the lack of facilities for any arithmetic in make itself, and the very limited arithmetic facilities of the default shell /bin/sh basically force you to use an external utility to produce the list of numbers to loop over, and you need to keep track of the top of the range yourself. (If you don't like Bash, maybe you have jot; or you could use a simple Perl one-liner like perl -le 'print for 1..3'.)
(Your syntax suggests that you are using GNU make. This syntax is not portable to POSIX make or other variants like BSD Make, Windows nmake, etc.)

Note that the OP want the value of the variables. Your proposal assigns to MYLIST the names of the variables (SUB_TEST1, ...) , not the values (PRJ1, ...)

The GNUmake table toolkit was designed with your usecase in mind:
include gmtt.mk

# define a table with 2 rows:    
define selection-table :=
2
SUB_TEST1    PRJ1
SUB_TEST2    PRJ2
SUB_TEST3    PRJ3
MAIN_TEST1   PRJx
MAIN_TEST2   PRJy
endef

# select column 2 from the table where glob-match returns a result
subtest-list := $(call select,2,$(selection-table),$$(call glob-match,$$1,SUB_*))
maintest-list := $(call select,2,$(selection-table),$$(call glob-match,$$1,MAIN_*))
$(info $(subtest-list))
$(info $(maintest-list))

Output:
PRJ1 PRJ2 PRJ3
PRJx PRJy

